# How can i conditionally load taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php template php files through functions.php

Tags: templates, taxonomy, conditional-content

I have a movie review site, i would like to conditionally load the taxonomies of actors and directors only if a option of my theme is active.
At the moment in the root theme folder I have these 2 files

```
taxonomy-actors.php
taxonomy-directors-php
```

I would like them to be used only if the function is active for example

```
if ($theme_comments == 1) 
{ 
 //load taxonomy-actors.php
} else {
//don't load taxonomy-actors.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution :)

Code:

```
if ($moviewp_comments == 1) { 

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_include' );
function wpse_template_include( $template ) {
    // Handle taxonomy templates.
    $taxonomy = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    if ( is_tax() && $taxonomy ) {
        $file = get_theme_file_path() . '/templates/taxonomy-' . $taxonomy . '.php';
        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            $template = $file;
        }           
    }

    return $template;
}
} else { 

}
```